# How to change background color of video bar after playing the video

Tags: html, css, mp4

When video stop playing I see this black shadow on the bar [image]

Does anybody know how to remove it?

Comment: Can you post your snippet of what you've tried so far here?

Comment: <video src="/api/File?identifier=4572da8a-9db8-4c7c-8058-d19039d34b3d" preload="auto" autoplay="" controls="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;/* outline: none; */"></video>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css to your video tag. This will remove the background color.

```css
 video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
   background-image: none !important;
  }
```

```html
<video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="" controls="" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;/* outline: none; */"></video>
```